# Exhausted Resultset Error

Tags: java, oracle11g

i have this code to get amount from Account table in my database
but i get this error : Exhausted Resultset

```
  public int accountAmount(int custID){
        int amount=0;
        try{
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection connection =
                    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl" , "MYATM","myjava123");
            PreparedStatement statment =  connection.prepareStatement("select amount from Account where cust_id=?");
            statment.setInt(1,custID);
            ResultSet resultSet=statment.executeQuery();

            resultSet.next();

            amount= resultSet.getInt("amount");

            statment.close();
            connection.close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

        }


       return  amount;
    }
```

Comment: Does your query return any results?

Comment: yes when i execute that query is in statment in sqlplus it return exactly value in Account table

Answer (score 2):

Check the return type of [ResultSet#next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29); spoiler - it's a boolean that (if false) indicates you're past the last row. So, instead of this

```
resultSet.next();
amount= resultSet.getInt("amount");
```

You need this!

```
if (resultSet.next()) {
  amount= resultSet.getInt("amount");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it right, before reading from the `resultset` check that `resultset.next()` returned true. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Your resultset is probably empty.  Try using it in like this to catch that state:

```
 if (rs.next()) {
     amount= resultSet.getInt("amount")
 }
 else {
     // result set is empty, throw an error?
 }
```

Comment: oops, dupe, got out-answered by @ElliottFrisch, points for you.

Comment: tanks in my java code the else block executed that means my resultset is empty but when i executed that query with sqlplus in cmd that give me true result exactly that amount is in Account table!!!

Comment: You might then debug the code and verify that custID is what it should be.